# What are the long term risks/side-effects of nicotine consumption?

Tags: side-effects, smoking

when reading about the long term effects of nicotine, almost every source refers to the long term effects of tobacco smoking. But what part does nicotine by itself have? I mean apart from immediate side effects like sickness, etc. How does it affect the body long term? 
e.g. When smoking tobacco you have a higher chance of heart-problems. As I understand, this is mainly due to the carbon-monoxide in the blood, increasing the load on your heart. But does nicotine play a role in this?
Which tobacco smoking long-term-effects/risks are actually due to nicotine and which come from you inhaling any sort of smoke, containing a few thousand toxins?